# Android: Record Audio for later Background Streaming to Speech-to-Text?

Tags: android, text, translation, speech

Within my Android app i want to be able to record spoken audio, online or offline, then, when i choose to, stream chunks of recorded audio to Google for Speech to Text transcribing all in the background so as to not affect the current Activity.  New voice recording and streaming / transcribing could be going on at the same time.

What classes should i look into to accomplish the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) API will do:

```
    recorder = new AudioRecord(
            AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, sampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize * 2);
```

Then inside the thread

```
private final class RecognizerThread extends Thread {

    private int remainingSamples;
    private int timeoutSamples;
    private final static int NO_TIMEOUT = -1;

    public RecognizerThread(int timeout) {
        if (timeout != NO_TIMEOUT)
            this.timeoutSamples = timeout * sampleRate / 1000;
        else
            this.timeoutSamples = NO_TIMEOUT;
        this.remainingSamples = this.timeoutSamples;
    }

    public RecognizerThread() {
        this(NO_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        recorder.startRecording();
        if (recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED) {
            recorder.stop();
            IOException ioe = new IOException(
                    "Failed to start recording. Microphone might be already in use.");
            mainHandler.post(new OnErrorEvent(ioe));
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Starting decoding");

        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

        while (!interrupted()
                && ((timeoutSamples == NO_TIMEOUT) || (remainingSamples > 0))) {
            int nread = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            if (nread < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error reading audio buffer");
            } else {
                boolean isFinal = recognizer.AcceptWaveform(buffer, nread);
                if (isFinal) {
                    mainHandler.post(new ResultEvent(recognizer.Result(), true));
                } else {
                    mainHandler.post(new ResultEvent(recognizer.PartialResult(), false));
                }
            }

            if (timeoutSamples != NO_TIMEOUT) {
                remainingSamples = remainingSamples - nread;
            }
        }

        recorder.stop();

        // Remove all pending notifications.
        mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

        // If we met timeout signal that speech ended
        if (timeoutSamples != NO_TIMEOUT && remainingSamples <= 0) {
            mainHandler.post(new TimeoutEvent());
        }
    }
```

Full example [here](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/87fc3bc07356549a951adb21537465f81d6d6763/android/src/main/java/org/kaldi/SpeechRecognizer.java#L179).

Comment: Thanks for the response Nikolay. I'm still analysing the provided code but from what i can tell it only records audio but does nothing to actually transcribe the audio into text.  Is there a specific web service command offered by Google which one can pass the recorded chunks to for transcribing?

Comment: Sure, see this sample https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech